# Problem with file locking

Tags: parallelization, asynchronous-processing

Before reporting this to Wolfram I want to make sure that I am not mistaken. I am using MMA version 13.0.1

The following will lock a file and then write "Hello" into it, all in the current kernel:

```
SessionSubmit[nam := "c:/tmp/test.txt";
 lok = nam <> "-lck";
 WithLock[lok, Put["Hello", nam]]
  ]
```

However, if we use a different kernel, nothing is written:

```
LocalSubmit[nam := "c:/tmp/test.txt";
 lok = nam <> "-lck";
 WithLock[lok, Put["Hello", nam]]
  ]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a problem in Version 13.0 with file locking in local tasks.

BUT: WithLock is HoldAll.
You are not specifying a lock file, but a lock variable named "lok".
Use With to force the variable value into WithLock, and also use the File[] wrapper to disambiguate.

```
LocalSubmit[
 nam := "/tmp/test.txt";
 With[{lok = nam <> "-lck"},
  WithLock[File[lok], Put["Hello", nam]]]]
```

This example will work in the upcoming version of Mathematica.

Comment: Tank you for your answer.  Unfortunately in 13.0.1 it is not yet fixed. In addition I noted that the task, submitted by "LocalSubmit" ,is not removed after it is finished. You have to call "TaskRemove"

Comment: I got an answer from Wolfram confirming the answer from Roman: "I see this has been addressed by our developers on SE. Things are broken, but fixed in the next version to be released in the no too distant future."